# Android application access internet via VPN

Tags: java, android, vpn, android-vpn-service

I am building Android application
I need to access to internet via vpn server into my application
Not using third application like hotspot shield 
vpn free or paid no problem

Answer (score 0):

VPNs are not all the same, so according to the type of VPN server you have, for example openvpn or CISCO Ipsec or others... You need to build a vpn service that connects to the VPN server when your application tries to send information over the internet.
Android supports it by default. You can check this out. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html